# Leave UI on when entering VR mode aframe

Tags: aframe

Is it possible to leave certain or all ui elements on when entering VR mode?

For example, if I want a health bar in screen-space while in VR mode how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If the ui elements are "2d" elements laid on top of the 3d scene I don't think you can carry those over into VR mode, but what you might be able to do is create "3d" UI elements in the scene that are in a fixed position relative to the camera.  Although according to Oculus having things like a HUD is discouraged (https://developer.oculus.com/design/latest/concepts/bp_app_ui/)